# ¿Cómo limitar el número de elementos con css grid?

Tags: css, grid

estoy creando filas y columnas con css grid.

El punto es que quiero saber cómo le hago para limitar cuántos elementos en total se mostrarán.

Si tengo por ejemplo 15 elementos (iguales) organizados en 3 columnas y quiero que hayan 3 filas para así tener un cuadro de 3x3 ¿cómo oculto el resto?

He probado con `overflow:hidden` pero evidentemente no es la solución, y tampoco quiero establecer un alto máximo al contenedor del grid porque hay items que varían el tamaño y luego sería más complicado hacerlo responsive...

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Andrés y bienvenido, te invito a que hagas el [tour] y así ganes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Sobre tu pregunta, podrías aclarar qué es lo que quieres lograr? Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/276516/edit) tu publicación para añadir tu código o lo que has intentado hasta ahora, también puedes adjuntar imágenes del resultado que tienes y esperas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe un pseudoselector para ello `nth-of-type`, solamente debes de especificarle los valores que deseas en la siguiente forma

```
[selector de elemento]:nth-of-type(n+[A partir de qué número])
```

y el selector se aplicará a partir del elemento que elijas *ad infinitum*.

```css
p:nth-of-type(n+15) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>
<p>16</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

En este ejemplo, mostramos solo los 9 primeros divs, usando bootstrap 3/4 y jquery.

```js
$('div .row div').hide();
$('div .row div:lt(9)').show();
```

```css
div .row div {
  background-color: #CFC;
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit ut pellentesque
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur velit sollicitudin adipiscing, elit ut
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit ut pellentesque
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur velit sollicitudin adipiscing, elit ut
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor velit sollicitudin sit amet
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit ut pellentesque
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit velit sollicitudin amet consectetur adipiscing, elit ut
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur velit sollicitudin adipiscing, elit ut pellentesque
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor velit sollicitudin sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit ut
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit ut pellentesque
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit velit sollicitudin amet consectetur adipiscing, elit ut
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit velit sollicitudin velit sollicitudin amet
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet velit sollicitudin consectetur adipiscing, elit ut pellentesque
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit ut
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit velit sollicitudin ut pellentesque
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet velit sollicitudin consectetur adipiscing, elit ut
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor velit sollicitudin sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit ut pellentesque
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing, elit ut
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Lorem velit sollicitudin ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```